# How to send time info to function in zsh-theme?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm a green hand on zsh. But I want to custom a zsh-theme for my own.

I want to ask that how to send time info to my function.

It approximately looks like:

```sh
function custom() {
    TIME_INFO=`date +%H%M`
    if [ $TIME_INFO -ge 700 ] && [ $TIME_INFO -le 2330 ]; then
        echo -n "%F{green}[$(date +%H:%M:%S)]%f"
    else
        echo -n "%F{yellow}[$(date +%H:%M:%S)]%f"
    fi
}

...
PROMPT+="$(custom)"
...
```

but this code cannot run correctly.

I saw that `PROMPT` can use `%* %D %T` and so on, to display the time info.

but another question occurred...

these format cannot send to my function. such as:

```sh
function custom() {
    TIME_DATA=$1
    TIME_SPLT=(${TIME_DATA//:/})
    if [ $TIME_SPLT -ge 700 ] && [ $TIME_SPLT -le 2330 ]; then
        echo -n "%{$F[green]%}[%*]%f"
    else
        echo -n "%{$F[yellow]%}[%*]%f"
    fi
}

...
PROMPT+="%{$(custom %*)%}"
...
```

Then error occurred: `no matches found: %*`

So I want to know how to modify my code that can make my idear works. QwQ

Answer (score 0):

You can put the prompt sequences directly in you variable, then use the `(%)` parameter expansion flag to expand them, and you can do the expansion immediately upon assigning to the parameter. You can also use `print` to expand prompt sequences.

```
custom() {
    TIME_INFO=${(%):-%D{%H%M}}
    if [ "${TIME_INFO}" -ge 700 ] && [ "${TIME_INFO}" -le 2330 ]; then
        print -l '%F{green}[%D{%T}]%f'
    else
        print -l '%F{yellow}[%D{%T}]%f'
    fi
}
```

Finally, I would skip using command substitution to set `PROMPT`, and use the `precmd` hook to redefine `PROMPT` on demand.

```
precmd () {
  TIME_INFO=${(%):-%D{%H%M}}
  if [ "${(%)TIME_INFO}" -ge 700 ] && [ "${(%)TIME_INFO}" -le 2330 ]; then
    PROMPT='%F{green}'
  else
    PROMPT='%F{yellow}'
  fi
  PROMPT+='[%D{%T}]%f'
}
```

(Note that there is a tiny race condition, though probably not one worth worrying about. It's possible that `TIME_INFO` gets set at 6:59:59, making your prompt yellow, but the assignment to `PROMPT` happens at 7:00:00. Likewise, you could set `TIME_INFO` at `23:30:59`, but `PROMPT` at `23:31:00`, resulting in a yellow time displayed as green.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it!